# Spring type conversion for EnumSet : all values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Question is about how Spring's build-in type converters work for `EnumSet` type.

Assuming the following Enum:

```java
public enum Color {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN
}
```

and standard binding:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myexample")
public class MyProperties {
    
    private EnumSet<Color> colors;

    public EnumSet<Color> getColors() {
        return colors;
    }

    public void setColors(EnumSet<Color> colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }
}
```

I would like in my properties file to be able to do

```
myexample.colors = <ALL>
```

which would be the equivalent of `EnumSet.allOf(Color.class)`. One can imagine other variations as well, for example complements:

```
myexample.colors = -GREEN
```

which would be the equivalent of `EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(Color.GREEN))`.

Before jumping into building my own converter I would like to figure out what Spring 5 already offers in this space. It wouldn't be totally unnatural if something like this was already present in the framework.

At the moment I cannot even figure out if Spring 5 has a dedicated type converter for `EnumSet` or if it simply uses a combination of `Set` and `Enum`. Perhaps a short test case
would help me to figure out what code path Spring follows when it does the `String` --> `EnumSet` conversion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. New to type conversion.

(Spring Boot 2.7, Spring Framework 5)

Comment: why not just use    List<String> colors ?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici That makes zero difference to the conversion service.

Comment: My expectation is that it's using converters from the `StringToEnumConverterFactory` and standardized collection behavior (split on string and parse individually). You could debug and set a breakpoint on `setColors` to see what the stack trace shows.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-:  The interesting part of the question is how Spring would deal with the `EnumSet` aspect, not so much the individual elements .. we already know that Spring is quite capable of doing that conversion.

Comment: There isn't. You can only convert from a `String` to an `Enum`. There isn't any operation possible. So you can write `myexample.colors=RED,GREEN` and it will be converted, but you cannot just write `myexample.colors=-BLUE` to get the same. It only works with specifying which values to use.